# Pandas melt function from wide to long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel files that I merged and pulled data frame as below.

```
import pandas as pd
foo = {'No':[1,2],'p1': [10,12],'p2':[15,18],'v1':[12,14],'v2':[15,8],'m1':[89,26],'m2':[56,89]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=foo)
```

my desired output is

```
foo_1={'No':[1,2,1,2],'p': [10,12,15,18],'v':[12,14,15,8],'m':[89,26,56,89]}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data=foo_1)
```

I have tried melt, wide to long but not been able to get the desired output.

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=list("pvm"), i="No", j="Num")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 > pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['p', 'v', 'm'], i='No', j='Dummy').reset_index().drop('Dummy', axis=1)
    No  p   v   m
0   1   10  12  89
1   2   12  14  26
2   1   15  15  56
3   2   18  8   89
```

This converts the columns using as the base names 'p', 'v', and 'm'. It uses 'No' as the original id, and labels the suffixes as 'Dummy', which it drops having reset the indices to regular columns.